# Magento 2 - Get URL data by request path

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I have gathered URLs from `sitemap.xml` now I need category ID against category URL and Product ID against product URL. I want to do it by getting URL data from  `url_rewrite` table

In Magento 1.9 we use this code to get data by request path

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath("abcPath");
```

How can we do it in **Magento 2**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging in magento core code I finally got solution.

I have used this code to get `url_rewrite` data by url key

```
    /* Find url data by request path */
    $filterData = [
        UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => $path
    ];

    $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($filterData);
    
    $type = $rewrite->getEntityType();
    $entityId = $rewrite->getEntityId();
    $targetPath = $rewrite->getTargetPath();
```

where `$this->urlFinder` is the instance of `\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface`

Hope it will help others too.

Comment: Please add the classes which you were using.

Comment: No, this is code from Magento 2. We don't know eiter and now we cant solve the issue and your answer is useless. So please always add all necessary informations.

Comment: @Black It's really easy to search Magento's codebase for `findOneByData` and find `Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface`. Takes 10 seconds. If you can't do this, you have other problems.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, there are multiple definitions of the method, so how do I know which one he used? If you don't have a clue about the subject then stop commenting. If you searched the project as you claim, then you should have seen it. I already tried that class, but it did not work with it. At the end I figured out that it was because of the visibility of the product, it was set to not be visible in the frontend, and thats why it failed.

Comment: @Black I have used above code, and it is working properly in my magento. `$this->urlFinder` is actually instance of `\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface`

Comment: Yes it works with the class, it did not worked because the product was not visible in the frontend as mentioned in the last comment.

Answer (score 2):

I have created one root script in pub/getUrlInfo.php below is the code which I have added in that script.

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$urlFinderInterface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

/// Below is the path of product or category you need to replace it. And if you want all products and category path then you need to add below code in loop
$path = "test1.html";

$filterData = [
    \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => $path
];

$rewrite = $urlFinderInterface->findOneByData($filterData);
if (!empty($rewrite)) {
    $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $entityId = $rewrite->getEntityId();
    $targetPath = $rewrite->getTargetPath();

    echo "ID: " . $entityId. "<br/>";
    echo "Request Path: " . $baseUrl . $path . "<br/>";
    echo "Target Path: " . $baseUrl . $targetPath . "<br/>";
}
```

Now you need to Run that script from terminal run below command from terminal.

```
php pub/getUrlInfo.php
```

You will get output like below.

```
ID: 1
Request Path: http://127.0.0.1/magento243P1/pub/test1.html
Target Path: http://127.0.0.1/magento243P1/pub/catalog/product/view/id/1
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: It works, thx! My attempt failed, because the product was set to not be visible in the frontend and so there was no entry in the **url_rewrite** table. Thats also important to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global function as below in your model or helper. Depending upon usage you might need to pass store id too.

```
<?php

namespace Yourvendor\Yourmodule\Model;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Yourclass
{
    /**
     * @var UrlFinderInterface
     */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get url rewrite based on request path
     *
     * @param string $requestPath
     * @param int $storeId|null
     * @return UrlRewrite|null
     */
    public function getRewrite($requestPath, $storeId = null)
    {
        if($storeId === null) {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        }

        return $this->urlFinder->findOneByData(
            [
                UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => ltrim($requestPath, '/'),
                UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $storeId,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```